# How to filter dataframe based on user input using streamlit and python

Tags: python, pandas, filter, streamlit

I have a datafarme that includes 3 columns  i want to allow the user to filter the result based on the user input  where the user can select which column to filter using a checkbox.

The problem is that if the user doesn't check the 2 checkbox it return the below error :

> df_result_search = df[df['age']==(age_search)]

> NameError: name 'age_search' is not defined

and if the user check all the checkbox and enter the values it return a wrong record while it takes only one value and filter based on it.

## code:

```
import streamlit as st 
import pandas as pd

data = {'name':['Tom', 'nick', 'krish', 'jack','Tom'],
        'nickname':['jack','krish','karim','joe','joe'],
        'age':[20, 18, 19, 18,22]}
 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df_result_search = pd.DataFrame() 


searchcheckbox_name_nickname = st.checkbox("Name or Nickname ",value = False,key=1)
searchcheckbox_age = st.checkbox("age",value = False,key=2)

if searchcheckbox_name_nickname:
    name_search = st.text_input("name")
    nickname_search = st.text_input("nickname")
if searchcheckbox_age:   
    age_search = st.number_input("age",min_value=0)
if st.button("search"):
    df_result_search = df[df['name'].str.contains(name_search,case=False, na=False)]
    df_result_search = df[df['nickname'].str.contains(nickname_search,case=False, na=False)]
    
    df_result_search = df[df['age']==(age_search)]
                    
    st.write("{} Records ".format(str(df_result_search.shape[0])))
    st.dataframe(df_result_search)
```

Comment: Here is a question, if name is Tom and nickname is jack and age is 0 or not indicated, what dataframe you would like to see?

Comment: based on the dataframe it  must return empty But if the user name is Tom and age is 20 the result must show 1 record  `tom jack 20`

Comment: So the name and nickname can be name only or nickname only and the age must be correct. Example, if name is Tom and nickname is aaa and age is 20, 1 record will be returned because name Tom is 20, is that correct?

Comment: first the user must check the check box so if he check the name or nickname he must enter a valid name or nickname that exist in the data ... if he check the age he must enter a valid age that exist in the data..... so the filter is done based on the checked column/s

Comment: How about this, name is Tom, nickname is joe and age is 19, what record to return?

Comment: if he check the name and nickname box  and enter `tom` as name which is valid  and `joe` which is valid but not related to `tom` it return empty result.... and as he check the age he must enter a valid age `19` is valid but is not related to the values before .. for this it  return an empty dataframe.

so as the user enter 3 values this mean that the filter must be done based on the 3 values while if he entered 2 values or 1 value the filter will be done on them.

can i perform filter based on this ??or am i doing something wrong ?

Comment: i edit my question and add one record  so if user enter **only**  `tom` as name the result must return 2 records ... if he enter one more parameter like age or nickname **(in order to narrow the search)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code updated, in case 3 with `pass  # continue here.`, you can continue writing the code when all checkboxes are checked.

##### Code

```py
import streamlit as st 
import pandas as pd

data = {'name':['Tom', 'nick', 'krish', 'jack', 'Tom'],
        'nickname':['jack','krish','karim','joe', 'joe'],
        'age':[20, 18, 19, 18, 22]}
 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
st.write(df)
df_result_search = pd.DataFrame() 


searchcheckbox_name_nickname = st.checkbox("Name or Nickname ",value = False,key=1)
searchcheckbox_age = st.checkbox("age",value = False,key=2)

if searchcheckbox_name_nickname:
    name_search = st.text_input("name")
    nickname_search = st.text_input("nickname")
else:
    name_search = ''
    nickname_search = ''

if searchcheckbox_age:   
    age_search = st.number_input("age",min_value=0)
else:
    age_search = 0

if st.button("search"):
    # 1. only name/nickname is checked
    if searchcheckbox_name_nickname and not searchcheckbox_age:
        # if name is specified but not the nickname
        if name_search != '' and nickname_search == '':
            df_result_search = df[df['name'].str.contains(name_search, case=False, na=False)]
        # if nickname is specified but not the name
        elif name_search == '' and nickname_search != '':
            df_result_search = df[df['nickname'].str.contains(nickname_search, case=False, na=False)]
        # if both name and nickname are specified
        elif name_search != '' and nickname_search != '':
            df_result_search = df[(df['name'].str.contains(name_search, case=False, na=False)) & (df['nickname'].str.contains(nickname_search, case=False, na=False))]
        # if user does not enter anything
        else:
            st.warning('Please enter at least a name or a nickname')

    # 2. only age is checked
    elif not searchcheckbox_name_nickname and searchcheckbox_age:
        if age_search != 0:
            df_result_search = df[df['age'] == age_search]
            
    # 3. if both name/nickname and age are checked
    else:
        pass  # continue here.
                    
    st.write("{} Records ".format(str(df_result_search.shape[0])))
    st.dataframe(df_result_search)
```

##### Sample output

The user only use the name checkbox and only fillup the name.

[image]

Comment: i tried your answer it solve the first error but now it return empty

Comment: I just tried to solve the error, the return value depends on your code after the button is pressed. Review your `df_result_search = df[df['name'].str.contains(name_search,case=False, na=False)]` and this `df_result_search = df[df['nickname'].str.contains(nickname_search,case=False, na=False)]` and this `df_result_search = df[df['age']==(age_search)]`. What do you really want?

Comment: i am trying to filter the dataframe based on these 3 columns where the user even search based on one of them or 2  of them  or all of them. isn't the code structure right ? or i am missing something ?

Comment: Your code is not correct because the last call is `df_result_search = df[df['age']==(age_search)]`, the two previous call will be ignored.

Comment: so how to get the correct result if the user input one or more values??

Comment: this was what i am looking for thank you for your help ... so if i want to add more fields i need to add more if statements?? isn't that will take more time ??

Comment: It will take time if there are more fields. Maybe there are ways to optimize it but first make it work.